# (SOLVED) Is it possible to use an AppImage as a default application in Elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera?

Tags: settings, applications, release-hera, thirdpartyapps

In the default applications settings, is it possible to set the default email client to an AppImage? I'm using a Tutanota Desktop client for Linux that's an AppImage file but I don't see a way to use it as my default email client & when I search online for solutions I just see articles & forum posts explaining how to integrate AppImages into the DE but I already know how to do that so I was wondering if any one knows of any solutions.

EDIT: I was told to "as root, open this with your text editor:
IE: sudo nano /usr/share/applications/defaults.list 
change it:
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop
x-scheme-handler/mailto=/path/to/myCoolEmail.appimage" and "protocol says if it is not installed at /usr/local/bin or /opt move it there." but when I did as instructed it still didn't make it where I could choose the AppImage file from the default applications settings. Is it not possible to do this? Would this suggested solution be a good workaround despite not making a difference in the settings GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution to my problem:
Download the Tutanota Appimage

Install the Main Menu application by running this line of code in the Terminal application:

sudo apt install alacarte

Find and select the Tutanota application in the Main Menu application. I found it in the left-hand list under Internet

Select Properties on the right-hand side

Find the Command line and add this string to the end:

MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto

Run this line of code in the Terminal application:
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications

At this point the Tutanota app should display as the default mail app if you check out settings.

Comment: While no fan of appimage, this is certainly an excellent answer to your own question. Thank you for leaving the basic guide on how to do it here for everyone.

Comment: No problem. I don't particularly like that they released it as an AppImage versus some other option but I'm glad I was able to integrate it into elementary after doing some research. Initially I couldn't find any solutions online but in a #linux channel on a slack workspace I'm in I found people who were able to help direct me to helpful articles on the subject that I failed to find on my own with the keywords I used in Google.